# What happened to RNN and Seq2seq options in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

It looks like lots of stuff was recently deprecated or moved to contrib, and it doesn't seem like there are any up-to-date equivalents in core. What was the reasoning behind this? I can't seem to find any GitHub issue or discussion explaining these changes. [Example GitHub search](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=embedding_attention_decoder)

Answer (score 0):

Around the time of the 1.0 release, we made a large effort to carefully choose what should be part of the "official" supported API and feature set, because anything included would have to be supported for a long, long time and becomes very hard to change.  The rules for stuff in contrib are less tight in terms of making non-backwards-compatible changes, so components judged likely to change substantially in the near future (i.e., to not be stable yet) were moved to contrib or elsewhere.